# How to track events in the Cordova app

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-analytics, analytics, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm creating an app using Cordova and I would love to have some analytics for my app so I can tell where users are clicking the most or what is a workflow for  clicks i.e. routes/paths (aka click-map or heat-map) i.e.

```
Page 1 -> Form 1 -> Option 2 - 80% of users

Page 1 -> Form 2 -> Option 1 - 5% of users

Page 2 -> Form 1 -> Option 3 - 15% of users or something like that.
```

Here are a few questions:

- So I'm looking for best practices or what would you suggest to use so I can get this or similar analytics?
- Is Google Analytics a right choice for that? Events or a Tag manager? Is there any other options?
- Is there any plugin or library for that?

Thank you!

Comment: Google Analytics is the right choice: [google-analytics-plugin](https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own analytics reporting in Javascript, independent of the Cordova component.  Or, you could use a Cordova plugin. There are several:
http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=analytics